# How to call code behind function from a html button click?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, app, .net

I am fighting with MVC in Provider hosted app and trying to implement
code behind function for html input button.

Below is the input button in .aspx page:

```
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btn" value="Save" onserverclick="Button1_ServerClick()" />
```

and function which is in .cs file is as follow:

```
 protected void Button1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

Can any one help me in knowing why I am not triggering the
function from .cs file?

Comment: Did you try using asp.net button instead? `<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_ServerClick" />`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC works differently than Web Forms. You can't just attach server-side event handlers to control. You should create controller action and then execute it using submit button, redirect or JavaScript (AJAX).

Read about [`Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx), [`ActionLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) and [`BeginForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) HtmlHelper extension methods (you can use them in Razor like `@Html.ActionLink(...)`). You may also be interested in [`Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) method of UrlHelper (you can use it like `@Url.Action(...)` in Razor).